# Material UI Button remove focus frame

Tags: typescript, sass, material-ui

Is there a way to remove the focus frame of a Material UI Button?

I tried to add a CSS class `.focusframe` with `box-shadow: none`, but this does not seem to remove the focus frame. When clicked, the button remains with this red focus frame.

TypeScript class with the Button rendering:

```
export class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
    public componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({sessionLoaded: true});
    }

    public render() {
        if (this.state) {
            return <div>
                <Button className='focusframe' onClick={() => console.log("Material UI Button clicked!")} color='primary' variant='contained'>Click Me!</Button>
            </div>;
        } else {
            return <div>State not yet accessible.</div>;
        }
    }
}
```

SCSS Class:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "_colors.scss";

body {
    background-color: $body-color-base;
    color: $body-color-font;

    .focusframe {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Before clicking the button:

[image]

After clicking the button:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

HTML of the button:

```
<div>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained focusframe MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
    <span class="MuiButton-label">
      Click Me!
    </span>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
    </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

SCSS-file _colors.scss:

```
$body-color-base: #343a40;
$body-color-font: #dddddd;
```

**Edit 2:**

This works if I set it globally:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work if I set it to the `.focusframe` class:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "_colors.scss";

body {
    background-color: $body-color-base;
    color: $body-color-font;

    .focusframe {
        :focus {
            outline: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That "focus frame" isn't coming from Material-UI. I suspect it is a side-effect of some of the global styles you are importing (e.g. "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap", "_colors.scss"). You should be able to inspect it using Chrome developer tools to determine where the styling is coming from.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Disable the [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) via CSS

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

based on your edit, your css selector is wrong:

```
body {
    background-color: $body-color-base;
    color: $body-color-font;

    .focusframe {
        &:focus { <--- & here
            outline: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Propably theres some rule more specific. Try using MuiButton-root:focus or button:focus

Comment: Ok, the ampersand '&' was the missing part. Thanks! Could you please explain what the ampersand exactly stands for?

Comment: In Sass/Scss it basically means concat the current selector with the outer one, so .focusframe { &:focus { ... } } its compiled in .focusframe:focus{ ... } instead .focusframe { :focus { ... } } its compiled in .focusframe :focus { ... } which its different. [Extra info](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

Comment: You might have to add ```!important``` to the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add style:

```
<style>
    button[class*="Mui"]:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use makeStyle hook as below

```js
import { Button, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        position:"fixed",
        bottom:0,
        right:0,
        border:0,
        '&:focus': {
            outline:0,
            border:0,
        }
    },
});

function ChatBtn({onClick}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Button
            className={classes.root}
            color="inherit"
            variant="outlined" 
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            
            onClick={onClick}
        >
            LIVE CHAT
        </Button>
    );
}

export default ChatBtn;
```